# Spark, small excel files, Pandas or Pyspark for performance?

Tags: python, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm working with small Excel files (10 000 rows or less) in spark (Databricks).

I need to do some transformations on the excel file and usually I use pandas to read in the file, convert to spark dataframe and then do transformations. But since learning more about Spark distributed architecture I'm thinking that this is not good for performance for such small files?

Should I just do all the transformations with Pandas (forcing it to run only on the driver node) and then converting to spark dataframe only when needed or does it not really matter?

Comment: I prefer to always do it with Spark (when possible) because if your code consumes too much memory and there is a driver node shutdown, the rest of your cluster will stop

Comment: 10K records is way too small for Spark.

Comment: Then how many of these 10K files do you have?

Comment: it depends, sometimes only 1, sometimes many. The general question is if I should do any kind of transformations for the excel files with Pandas (driver node only) or should I convert it to Spark dataframe and use pyspark?